# final security steps on javacard

Tags: security, javacard, globalplatform

I've written my applet and installed on my card. what should I do to prevent further modification or installation of applet on my java card?

I have read that I should change default key set. I tried GPShell but I could not change keys!

I tried jcManager but it could not recognize my readers (acs and REINERSCT)!

how can I finalize my card to deliver user. Can any one tell me finalization steps to make my card safe?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change Authentication Keys:**

*GPShell* and *JCManager* are really old tools that not supported anymore. Try to use newer tools such as **GlobalPlatformPro** [[Its executable file download link]](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases).

Command to change default authentication keys using GPPro:

```
gp -lock <PutTheNewKeyHere>
```

And to reverse the above operation(Changing the new key to the default value):

```
gp -key <TheAboveNewKey> -unlock
```

More commands described [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#get-it-now).

**Change Life Cycle of your applet and Security Domain:**

To change the life cycle of your card, you can use *SET STATUS* APDU command:

Examples:

_OP_READY_ To *INITIALIZED* : `80 F0 P1 07 |Lc| AID`

*INITIALIZED* To *SECURED* :  `80 F0 P1 0F |Lc| AID`

`P1 = 40` : For Applications (Including SSDs)

`P1 = 80` : For ISD

**Make your applet the Default Selected applet:**

To install your applet as the DEFAULT SELECTED applet, use `-default` option with the installation command in GPPro:

`GP -install <PathToYourCapFile> -default`

(if you changed the card manager authentication keys, you need `-key` option in the command too).

---

You can also change ATR of the card to make it hard to recognize your card type by its ATR. To change the ATR, you can use `SetATRHistBytes()` method in *Global Platform* APIs.

Comment: Application Life Cycles are different! : 1. INSTALLED | 2. SELECTABLE | 3. PERSONALIZED | 4. LOCKED

Comment: @Abraham is that enough to change applet and ISD life cycle to SECURED? or I should disable selection of ISD and prevent further load/delete commands?

Comment: @PaulBastian should I set state for ISD and applet to secured or there will be sth else needed?

Comment: @M.Jalali If you want to be able to do further modification on your card contents in the future, you shouldn't disable selection of ISD. Because after disabling it, you can't delete or install any applet anymore (Same for  prevent further load/delete commands). Not all cards support disabling load/delete commands. I think it is enough to change ISD keys. If you use GP Secure channel APIs in your card, people can make problem for you with repetitive wrong authentication tries.

Comment: @PaulBastian Yes, they are. The examples are for ISD. For Applications and Packages, questioner can check Page 113 of GlobalPlatform v2.2 Specification.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way around changing the Issuer Security Domains keys. Beyond that there are multiple security guidelines to protect your card that are described by the Global Platform specification. To meantion some:

- Load FileData Block Hash/Signature (make sure you loaded on card what you actually intended to)
- Change Life Cycle of the Card to secured
- Change Life Cycle of your applet or finalize your personalization process by any other meaning
- **Change the Card Manager keys or your ISD or other SDs**
- Disable the GP Load/Delete command(proprietary)
- Disable selection of the Card Manager(proprietary)

Changing the Card Manager keys is the most important and standard one. Diversification might be used.
Try another tool like [GP Pro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) or check all your actions again.